# How to pass Tweetinvi search result from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tweetinvi

I am using Tweetinvi a .NET C# library to access the Twitter REST API.

this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SeatchTweetModel search)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Auth.SetUserCredentials("MyCONSUMER_KEY", "MyCONSUMER_SECRET", "MyACCESS_TOKEN", "MyACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");

        var searchText = search.TextToSearch;
        var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchText );

        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    return View();
}
```

I tried `ViewBag` but NullReferenceException occured.

What will be the best way to render tweets search result to view,

this is my model,

```
public class SeatchTweetModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required")]
    [DisplayName("Search Tweet")]
    [StringLength(160, ErrorMessage =("Max 160 character allowed"))]
    public string TextToSearch { get; set; }         
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way for passing data from controller to view is store them in model.

```
return View(model);
```

Yo can add another property in model and store results there.

For example: Add new property Tweets to your model class.

Model variable is accessible from the view - you can declare it that way:

```
@model SeatchTweetModel
```

In the view you can access your data by: @Model.Tweets.

Comment: can you explain little more